# int8_t* is not compatible for strlen() function; How to resolve this issue?

Tags: c++, strlen

I am not able to use `int8_t*` type inside the `strlen()` function, it gives error like

> invalid conversion from int8_t* to const char*`

Please help me, how to resolve this issue?

If I change the type from `int8_t*` to `char*` then it is working fine, but I can't use `char*` as per my project coding guidelines I have to use either `int8_t` or `uint8_t`, so please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is this a duplication? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381855/int8-t-and-char

Comment: I think it is not duplicate, I want to know, is there any other method similar like strlen() for int8_t types?

Comment: You either must cast or must write your own version of `strlen` that operates on a sequence of `int8_t` elements.

Comment: How to cast from "int8_t*" to "const char*"?

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying? Are you trying to send an int8_t into strlen?

Comment: @sokid Do your guidelines actually say never to use `char` or not to use `char` for things that aren't conceptually *characters*?  *Never* using `char` is ridiculous.  Your other question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744226/int8-t-vs-char-which-is-the-best-one ) makes me think it's something like the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" to this is one of three things:

1. Use `char` instead of `int8_t`.
2. Write your own `strlen` type function.
3. Cast `int8_t` to `char` at the callsite.

The cast solution would look something like this:

```
int8_t something[100];
... something gets set somehow ... 
size_t len = strlen((char *)something);
```

or in C++:

```
size_t len = strlen(static_cast<char *>(something));
```

Personally, I think option 1 is the "right" one if the data being processed is really string data. That is what the `char` type is for, but not what `int8_t` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `int8_t` unless it meets your requirements. It is **not** a synonym for `char`. It is a signed integral type that has **exactly** 8 bits, and it won't exist on platforms that don't have 8-bit integral types. When you want to deal with `char` objects, use the type `char`. That's what it's for.