# note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int8_t *’

Tags: c, gcc

code:

```
int8_t ret;
int8_t buf[8];
bytes_written = snprintf(buf, 8, "%" PRId8, 2);
```

warning:

```
warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘snprintf’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
     bytes_written = snprintf(buf, 8, "%" PRId8, 2);
     ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:386:12: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int8_t *’
 extern int snprintf (char *__restrict __s, size_t __maxlen,
```

I know this can be fixed by taking buf as *char, but

> int8_t is typedef as unsigned char

checked with pre-processor output i.e. `gcc main.c | grep int8_t`

So why compiler is not able to understand that?

With buf as uint8_t also I get the same warning.

Edit:

> int8_t is typedef as signed char (By mistake I have written as unsigned in original post)

Comment: What is `PRId8`. Should the call to `snprintf` not be `bytes_written = snprintf(buf, 8, "%PRId8", 2);` ?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744226/int8-t-vs-char-which-is-the-best-one

Comment: @Nishant No, `PRId8` is a CPP macro.

Comment: @Lundin I use CPP to mean C Preprocessor.

Comment: @a3f Aah :)  No, CPP is an abbreviation for C++.

Comment: @Nishant No that part it is correct. Take a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6299346/3436922)

Comment: @Lundin "cpp" *is* the name of the C pre-processor, at least as it comes with GCC.

Comment: @alk So the G++ pre-processor is called CPPPP?

Comment: I'd say G++ and GCC use the same CPP. ;-) @Lundin

Comment: Nice one, Lundin. By way of interest there are only three occurrences of "cpp" is the ISO C11 standard and none of them refer to the preprocessor. In a *stunningly apt* use of the English language, ISO insists on calling this the ... wait for it ... preprocessor :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sprintf` family of calls require a `char *` buffer in which to write their data.

You currently have it as `int8_t *` (a *signed* 8-bit value) and the fact that it's complaining about the signedness of the type almost certainly means the naked `char` is unsigned on your system (the standard leaves it open as to whether or not `char` is a signed or unsigned type) or that `gcc` is clever enough to realise this may be a portability issue on other compilers.

Be aware that's a *warning* so it will probably still work. However, I like to clean up code like that so as to make my life easier down the track.

The fix is, of course, to use the correct type (either by changing the type to `char buf[8]` or by explicitly casting it in the `snprintf` call, thereby telling the compiler you know what you're doing).

Comment: `char` is a distinct type from `signed char` and `unsigned char` regardless.

Comment: @paxdiablo It gave same warning with *buf* as uint8_t also. I am compiling code with gcc and that consider char as signed char by default